# How do I append data with Oracle's impdp?

Tags: oracle, impdp

Does `impdp` always truncate the table before it loads the data even if I don't recreate the meta data? If it does, is there an option to tell it to append the data instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `impdp` does for existing tables is controlled by the [`TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION` parameter](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_import.htm#sthref364).

```
impdp hr/hr TABLES=employees DIRECTORY=dpump_dir1 DUMPFILE=expfull.dmp TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=APPEND
```

However, if you're already using `CONTENT=DATA_ONLY` which it sounds like you are `TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION` should be defaulting to `APPEND` so I'm not sure why you're seeing the behaviour you describe.